# Accurate weight scale to the gram

Tags: weight-loss, calories, bodyweight

I am interested in getting a very reliable and accurate weight scale that is accurate to the gram.
Not interested in any smart scale etc.
Googling I see some "smart" options and the non-smart ones seem more of the bathroom type scales quality or at least I don't know how to evaluate which one is good.
I am not sure if a question about a recommendation is acceptable here, so I'd ask how can I evaluate if a weight scale is reliable and accurate.

Comment: As you guessed, we don't give purchase recommendations here. As far as answering how to evaluate if a weight scale is accurate, what kind of scale are you talking about? Kitchen, or bodyweight scale?

Comment: @EricWarburton: body weight scale, but very accurate to the gram granularity. E.g. not just 80.9 but 80.9234 or similar

Comment: To test if a scale is accurate, you'll need calibration weights which are little weights of known weight. Large scales may need some really heavy ones to get them to read, and those aren't particularly cheap.

Comment: @DeeV: I am ok if is a bit more expensive. I am looking for something better than a regular bathroom scale. And I would prefer not to spent time figuring out if it is calibrated etc if possible

Comment: @DeeV: Or are you saying that this calibration testing is required regardless of the price of the scale?

Comment: I'm curious, what are you measuring that you need it to be that accurate?

Comment: @EricWarburton: Keeping a log of daily weight adjustments for a period of time that are not expected to be large enough per day to be "visible" by a regular bathroom scale except after a long time interval

Comment: You may just want to build your own w/ strain gauges. Gram "accuracy" will end up as meaningless noise, though, IMO. All scales should be calibrated if you want that kind of accuracy at bodyweight levels.

Comment: Your weight will fluctuate several pounds per day. I average about 4-5 lbs difference in the morning vs the night. This will depend on when food/liquids go in and out of your system. Unless you are planning on weighing every piece of food/liquid that goes into your body, it is completely unnecessary since 99% of the daily changes you experience through a hyper accurate scale will just be measuring your food. It is better to just measure once a week at the same time of day and notice the trends, and adjust your food intake accordingly.

Comment: Even then, measuring yourself daily is not only overkill, but it will kill your motivation from day to day. I would not recommend for any fitness goal. If you are just doing it for fun, or just like being overly meticulous I guess it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @EricWarburton: I understand that, it is just an experimental observation.

Comment: @DaveNewton:`build your own w/ strain gauges` I don't understand what this sentence means. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Jim It means "build a scale using strain gauges as the measuring sensor(s)." A strain gauge is a mechanism that converts distortion/displacement to resistance, which can then be used to calculate a weight. A commercial 100kg scale w/ 1g reading (which is different yet than 1g *accuracy*) will likely be fairly expensive. And again--that level of accuracy really isn't going to be particularly helpful. It's two-*thousandths* of a pound. That's just not useful information.

Comment: I am also curious why you feel you need weight into the thousandths? Even clinical published studies do not go down to that level of granularity. As far as smart scales, etc, scales are always accurate to themselves, while two scales may be different they will each be accurate to their own measurements, It's the bodyfat reading that is crap. Your best bet is a clinical medical scale properly calibrated.

Comment: @JohnP: thousands? No just increments of 1 gram. That was an example, would be ok with e.g. `80.12`

Comment: @Jim 1g *is* thousandths of a pound (0.0022 IIRC). Even hundredths of a pound is too noisy to be of value, IMO. There just isn't usable information there in almost all circumstances. A (reasonably-priced) medical-grade beam scale (say $500-ish) will be around ~50g resolution, or ~0.1lb. That's about as accurate as you need to be, really.

Comment: @DaveNewton but I am interested in kg not pounds.

Comment: @Jim ... So switch the mode on the scale? You said you wanted "increments of 1g" which is thousandths-of-a-pound accuracy. It doesn't matter what units we're using in conversation, the accuracy is the same.

Answer (score 2):

When looking for a scale you also need to specify capacity.  A typical bathroom scale is 150kg, but medical scales are often available to accommodate more massive people.

For the sake of argument, I will assume you need at least 100kg capacity which means with 1g resolution, the scale must have 100,000 divisions.  Those certainly exist, but it does require more careful engineering than a consumer scale.

Physicians scales are commonly capable of 100g resolution but I've spotted at least one with 50g resolution.  They should meet their specifications on accuracy (typically given in terms of linearity and repeatability,) and precision (normally stated as readability.)  As the comments have been saying, your daily weight fluctuations make higher precision of limited use, unless you are performing an experiment and addressing ingestion and excretion of food/water.

However, veterinary scales are available with a greater number of divisions.   Unless your subject is small for a human adult, better than 50g is going to be tricky.  There are veterinary **analytical** scales that have 100,000+ divisions but they are focused on smaller lab animals and I haven't seen one above 32kg capacity.  Which is unfortunate, because a key feature of veterinary scales is that they average the weight over time to account for the fact that living animals cannot keep still enough to get a steady reading with this much precision being expected.

There are industrial scales with sufficient divisions that they meet the requirements for both capacity and resolution, though one would have to check with the vendor on whether it supports dynamic weighing to allow for fluctuations caused by a living subject.

To touch on a point raised in the comments, you cannot get this level of precision without taking care to eliminate sources of error.  The scale needs to be placed/installed per the manufacture's specifications with regards to being level, a stable foundation to avoid problems with vibration, and temperature stability.  Some scales have internal calibration masses, but external calibration with 1 or more precision masses is not uncommon.  You might find a new scale for less than $1000 that just squeaks by your requirements, but $2000-$4000 seems more likely.  Relaxing the precision mandate will make it much more affordable.

Comment: The IPF uses a fancy scale which is within 20g. Beyond that, I agree, you're looking in the legal-for-trade area and any of those scales that can weigh 150kg at ±0.001kg are going to be north of $15k USD.

Comment: I don't actually need "at least 100kg" capacity. But at most "100 kg capacity". I.e. nobody weight is over 100kg. Also no it would be way over 32kg

Comment: @Jim Cheapest I found that *claims* 1g accuracy @ 100kg is $4500, and I’m skeptical they mean accuracy (as opposed to reading). It’s still not clear what you think you’ll be measuring—if the goal is to target metabolic processes it’ll be opaque and inaccurate. I don’t see any way to understand what’s noise vs. meaningless data—1g at 150lbs is like 0.001% of the weight. That kind of accuracy, where a heartbeat will cause fluctuation… again—what is the purpose?

Comment: @DaveNewton: I didn't think that it is so complicated. I am interested in keeping a log for daily changes of weight to avoid weighting e.g. 4 weeks to see the variation in a usual bathroom scale. Since it is non trivial, what would be the best option for an accurate digital scale? E.g. I have one currently that does not seem to have anything to change the calibration if the weight is off (perhaps too cheap)

Comment: @Jim How do you know the weight is off? Here’s the thing: our weight fluctuates a *lot*. If you’re just trying to track your weight then you need to measure a *trend*, which takes time by definition. The best you can do is weigh at roughly the same time, under the same conditions, every day (e.g., upon waking). Then keep doing that. With a typical reading of 0.1lb accuracy. In general the more you spend the more accurate and repeatable it’ll be.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Once a day measurement under the same conditions is what I had in mind as well. What would be a reasonable price for a good bathroom type scale then? I suppose "the more you spend..." should have some range since it wont be a "professional" grade scale then

Comment: @Jim Un-connected, digital scale? I mean... For all practical purposes, $30-150? Again pointing out that only the long-term trend matters; day-to-day can still vary quite a bit. Once-a-week, or even month, is sufficient to capture most trends. This is where a connected scale is handy, e.g., just get on it whenever, like in the AM and before showers, and let the app determine normal ranges, do the data smoothing, etc. And use the month graph as the only feedback--not the individual measurements.

Comment: @DaveNewton: ah so you recommend a smart scale? Is that only for convenience i.e. for gathering the data etc or is it more reliable. Because all else being equal I'd rather not get a smart scale

Comment: @Jim It is for convenience, because then I don't have to do any math myself (or only once in code, anyway). I don't know if they're "more reliable" outside of the same "more $ *tends* to be more accurate/reliable" matrix. It sure seems like you're over-thinking all this. Just buy a scale.